# Adding custom parameters to .APK or QR-code

Tags: android, apk

I’m building an Android application that I want to publish only once, but want it to connect to 2 different servers. The application will be downloadable with a QR-code

For example, my friend has a moviedatabase on his own server and I have one. Without manually writing the server url in the application settings, I wanted to modify the .APK file or the QR code, giving it a parameter. So when my friend scans in the QR-code which I make for him, I want his app to connect with his server. When I scan my QR-code I wanted it to connect to mine. Right after the installation of the .APK.

Is this possible? Or are there any suggestions how I can put the server url “somewhere” without entering it manually in the code?
There is another option. Making a textfield that the user can fill by scanning a QR-code. But for me, that is still manually entering the URL.

Any suggestions or advice are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem to store server url in preferences and make an extra Activity to grab qr from camera and change the preference

Comment: Thanks, as Rich already said too.. I stripped the QR-scanner and implemented in my view. I will use it to get server url and replace the "blank" preference.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported functionality on install.  There's no way to link to an Android Market url with extra information to be executed as a post-install script.  You can include a QR code scanner in your app (I believe ZXing is open source and/or free to use, for example), and you can have the server info encoded in the QR code.  You can save this to any persistent storage (such as SharedPreferences or SQLite) and then use this for all future data requests.